# Delete all observations, which are doubled on some variable

Tags: sas

Suppose **i have** a table:

```
Name Age
Bob  4
Pop  5
Yoy  6 
Bob  5
```

**I want** to delete all names, which are not unique in the table:

```
Name Age
Pop  5
Yoy  6
```

ATM, my **solution is** to make a new table with counts of unique names:

```
Name Count
Bob  2
Pop  1
Yoy  1
```

And then, leave all, which's `Count > 1`

I believe there are much more beautiful solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly there are two ways to do it:

**The SQL Procedure**

In SAS you may not need to use a summarisation function such as MIN() as I have here, but when there is only one of `name` then `min(age) = age` anyway, and when migrating this to another RDBMS (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server) it may be required:

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select name, min(age) as age
  from have
  group by name
  having count(*) = 1;
quit;
```

**Data Step**

Requires the data to be pre-sorted:

```
proc sort data=have out=have_stg;
  by name;
run;
```

When doing SAS data-step by group processing, the first. (first-dot) and last. (last-dot) variables are generated which denote whether the current observation is the first and/or last in the by-group. Using SAS conditional logic one can simply test `if first.name = 1 and last.name = 1`. Reducing this using logical shorthand becomes:

```
data want;
  set have_stg;
  by name;
  if first.name and last.name;
  /* Equivalent to:*/
  *if first.name = 1 and last.name = 1;
run;
```

I left both versions in the code above, use whichever version you find more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `proc sort` with the `nouniquekey` option. Then use `uniqueout=` to output the unique values and `out=` to output the duplicates (the `out=` statement is necessary if you don't wan't to overwrite your original dataset).

```
proc sort data = have nouniquekey uniqueout = unique out = dups;
  by name;
run;
```